# Where can I download air.app.AppEntry for Android and Adobe AIR development?

Tags: android, air

I've been looking everywhere. Basically I need to extend air.app.AppEntry so I can access the main launch Activity in my Android app. Anyone know where I can get or create this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://mobile.dzone.com/news/extending-air-android

It`s not  simple (or  clean) but still..